# Python Selenium Timeout Exception doesn't release previous memory, how to delete this memory leak?

Tags: python, selenium, memory-leaks, timeout, phantomjs

When my request trigger Timeout Exception, memory usage of python process in task manager/system monitor always increase. I didn't realized it if I ignore the exception, because the process will be killed by system.
But when I try to get some new url request after timeout exception, I realize that the memory usage was increased. If the request succeed, it doesn't leave any memory leaks. What is the difference of handler when it succeed load page and trigger Timeout Exception? Why timeout exception doesn't remove the previous memory? Is there any way to remove the memory leaks?

```
def run():
    try:
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)

        driver.get(url)

        driver.quit()
        del driver

        run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise 
    except:
        print " ::: TIMEOUT "
        driver.quit()

        del driver
        driver = None
        gc.collect()

        #here, python process (memory usage) in Task Manager / System Monitor always increase. if I call this function recursively, memory leak always increase when Timeout exception triggered.
```

==== 
Python 2.7
Selenium 2.42.1
PhantomJS 1.9.7

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the victims of this behaviour.
I have not tried PhantomJS, i am using Chromedriver.

in the last exception block what you can do is you can use Os methods to release the resources forcefully.

in windows you can do it like this.

```
os.system("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f /t >nul 2>&1")
```

This kills all the chromedriver instances. or replace chromedriver.exe with whatever resources you want.

generally it is best practice to catch TimeOutException in one block and rest in another except block.
be careful while using the above code, it will kill all the current chromedriver.exe programs and also all the sub processes it has started.

[edit]
you can also use some other method to achieve this